# Postition a div to a document width?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Basically, At the moment I have a button on my site that animates the entire page to the left and more or less shows another "page", I've set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/z7Xpu/) with what I have already, although my question is:

Is there a way to offset the "second page" by the say "resolution" of the users computer?

I can do this the way I have it, but if I have say a computer who's resolution is larger or smaller than 1920 x 1080. The second page wont be in the correct position, or "right next to" the first page! :(

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/z7Xpu/

Comment: you mean users screen resolution or browser viewport ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function fitToScreen(){
   var dimensions = {
      'height' : $(window).height() + 'px',
      'width' : $(window).width() + 'px'
    };

    $('#myPage').css(dimensions);
}
```

---

```
$(function(){    
    fitToScreen();    //on load

   $(window).resize(fitToScreen); //will call when window is resized
});
```

This will set the dimensions to the viewport's `width` x `height` at that point in time.

Comment: This works perfectly! But, what if the user changes the size of the window from the load? Can we make it adapt if the screen size has changed?

Comment: You will have to execute this from within a `$(window).resize()` handler.

Comment: I've Tried and failed of course, is this what you meant? http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/z7Xpu/2/

Comment: Wait, I believe I've got it, but is that the best way to do it? http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/z7Xpu/3/

Comment: I've moved that snippet into a function that can be called whenever required. So, it can be called as a callback for `.resize()`.

Answer (score 0):

In short id say use jquery and do something like
(**Pseudo code coming**)

```
var sWidth =s screens width
var sHeight =s screens height
```

then

```
var box =s your "second page box id"
```

then with jquery something like

box.css("width", sWidth);

box.css("height", sHeight);

etc...This is all pseudo code but you get the idea

Comment: I have no Idea what pseudo code is sorry ;( Is there anyway you could edit the fiddle I uploaded as an example please? :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dFHuS/)

I think this will work perfectly for you